# How to reference one PCL from another

Tags: c#, portable-class-library, visual-studio-2017

I make 2 Portable class libraries in VS2017: ProjectA and ProjectB. I set them both up in exactly the same way with Targets ".Net Framework 4.6" and "ASP.NET Core 1.0".

But when I right mouse click references on ProjectA to add a reference to ProjectB I get the error:

> Unable to add a reference to project 'ProjectB'. The targets of
>   Portable Library project 'ProjectB' are not the same or compatible
>   with the targets of the current Portable Library project.
>
> A Portable Library project's targets can be changed via the Library
>   tab in the project's properties

I followed the tip and the targets are the same.

For Sinatr: Here is a screen shot of a similar project, both ProjectA and ProjectB have exactly the same targets. Only the default namespace and assembly are different

[image]

How can I reference ProjectB?

Comment: *"set them both up in exactly the same way"* - it is worth to check it again. Would be nice if you add screenshots proving you did it *same way*.

Comment: There are plenty bug reports with same problems when using xamarin: [click](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=43198), [click](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2847/portable-class-libraries-do-not-work), [click](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=9276).

Comment: @Sinatr, I hope the above screen shot helps. Both projects really are the same..

Comment: If when I add a reference I browse to the bin/debug folder. Then it works. But I find this solution unsatisfactory..